# Valid regular expression for validation oracle Number

Tags: c#, java, javascript, jquery, oracle

How can i write valid regular expression for Oracle's **Number(2,2)**, Also digits after decimal should be either, 1 or 2 but not more than 2,also it can be optional. The numer should never start with [1-9] but can start with 0.

```
 Valid Number are -:
    0
    0.00
    0.12
    0.14



  Invalid are
    0.
    1
    1.00
    2.00
    0.000
```

Comment: Octal: `0[0-7]*`, note: `0` is an octal number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expresion you want is:

```
^0(\.[\d]{n,m}[1-9])*$
```

Let m and n be 2 non negative integers,and be n+1 the minimum acceptable decimals and m+1 the maximun acceptable decimals. This prevents 0.000..0 btw.

Comment: if i want to extend it for Number(4,4) or Number(6,6) ?

Comment: I fixed it for you to extend it, as you need.